# How to maintain average elevation of water on uneven terrain?

Tags: water

We have uneven terrain (street) and want to distribute water fairly equally to all locations (homes). The issue is that the locations at the end get sufficient water and other locations need to wait.

The water supply is not metered, so is there any other way we can fix this issue so every location gets an equal amount of water?

[image: Locations at the end get more water than others]

Comment: This is more of a civil engineering question than earth sciences. I believe the way to do it is to use valves and/or smaller diameter pipe to regulate the flow so less water reaches the locations at the end.

Comment: Agree this is really an engineering question. Pressure regulating valves are readily available and could be installed on the main or at each off-take

Comment: this question looks a lot like schoolwork if it is you might take a look at how the romans solved this problem.